# Unable to install fastText for python on windows.

Tags: python-3.x, fasttext

So I am unable to install fasttext for python on windows.  I followed the methods mentioned [in this issue](https://github.com/salestock/fastText.py/issues/91)

When I enter `python setup.py install`, I get the following error:

`error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

I tried using the wheel at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fasttext. It does install a module, however the name of the module is **fasttext** unlike **fastText** that gets installed on Ubuntu following the method mentioned in `Readme.md`. Also the `fasttext` module that does get installed is unable to load a prebuilt model like `wiki.de.bin`. I get an error saying `Cannot load ../fasttext/wiki.es/wiki.es.bin due to C++ extension failed to allocate the memory` [Relevant issue](https://github.com/salestock/fastText.py/issues/115).

I have created an issue [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/606), and am asking the same question here, hoping to get a faster response from this community.

Comment: [`fastText`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python) is the official Python binding module by Facebook. [`fasttext`](https://github.com/salestock/fastText.py) is another module/package currently published on PyPI but it is no longer developed and has known memory issues. I changed the wheels at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fasttext to the bindings by Facebook.

Comment: you mentioned memory errors with **fasttext** from the old wheels. The new wheels are for **fastText**.

Comment: @cgohlke It works now. Please post the answer so that I may accept it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With the help of @cgohlke comment above, I was able to install it for windows. Just go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fasttext. Download the wheel depending on your version. `pip install .whl file`. It works now.

Comment: The link appears to be broken. :(

Comment: Update 05/05/23 : the link and the solution provided worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create my environment with python=3.8. This allowed me to install fasttext on my pc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Download `Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools` and install `MSVC v140 - VS2015 C++ Build Tools` (v14.00). It’s located in the Individual components tab of Visual Studio Installer.

Then, `pip install fasttext`.