# How to workaround an installation issue on installing the fastText library on Windows?

Tags: python, installation, cmd, nlp, fasttext

I am new to this field and experimenting different models in NLP domain. While am trying to install the [fastText](https://fasttext.cc/) libary using the command prompt, it is showing an error:

```
pip install wheel
pip install pybind11
pip install fasttext
```

The error is:

```
Collecting fasttext
  Using cached fasttext-0.9.2.tar.gz (68 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.2 in c:\users\manid\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from fasttext) (2.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7.0 in c:\users\manid\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from fasttext) (69.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\manid\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from fasttext) (1.26.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: fasttext
  Building wheel for fasttext (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [75 lines of output]
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:476: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.

              By 2024-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\fasttext
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\FastText.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\fasttext
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\fasttext
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\fasttext\util
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\util\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\fasttext\util
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\fasttext\util
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\fasttext\tests
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\tests\test_configurations.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\fasttext\tests
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\tests\test_script.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\fasttext\tests
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\fasttext\tests
      running build_ext
      building 'fasttext_pybind' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\python
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\python\fasttext_module
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\python\fasttext_module\fasttext
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\python\fasttext_module\fasttext\pybind
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include -IC:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include -Isrc -IC:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tppython/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.obj /EHsc /DVERSION_INFO=\\\"0.9.2\\\"
      fasttext_pybind.cc
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): error C2672: 'pybind11::init': no matching overloaded function found
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1932): note: could be 'Ret pybind11::init(CFunc &&,AFunc &&)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'CFunc', type expected
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1924): note: or       'Ret pybind11::init(Func &&)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'Func', type expected
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1912): note: or       'pybind11::detail::initimpl::constructor<Args...> pybind11::init(void)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'Args', type expected
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): error C2672: 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def': no matching overloaded function found
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1631): note: could be 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(pybind11::detail::initimpl::pickle_factory<Args...> &&,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1625): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(pybind11::detail::initimpl::factory<Args...> &&,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1618): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(const pybind11::detail::initimpl::alias_constructor<Args...> &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1611): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(const pybind11::detail::initimpl::constructor<Args...> &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1599): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(const T &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1574): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(const char *,Func &&,const Extra &...)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): note: 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(const char *,Func &&,const Extra &...)': expects 3 arguments - 1 provided
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): error C2672: 'pybind11::init': no matching overloaded function found
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1932): note: could be 'Ret pybind11::init(CFunc &&,AFunc &&)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'CFunc', type expected
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1924): note: or       'Ret pybind11::init(Func &&)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'Func', type expected
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1912): note: or       'pybind11::detail::initimpl::constructor<Args...> pybind11::init(void)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'Args', type expected
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): error C2672: 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def': no matching overloaded function found
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1631): note: could be 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(pybind11::detail::initimpl::pickle_factory<Args...> &&,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1625): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(pybind11::detail::initimpl::factory<Args...> &&,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1618): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(const pybind11::detail::initimpl::alias_constructor<Args...> &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1611): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(const pybind11::detail::initimpl::constructor<Args...> &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1599): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(const T &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\manid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1574): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(const char *,Func &&,const Extra &...)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): note: 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(const char *,Func &&,const Extra &...)': expects 3 arguments - 1 provided
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fasttext
  Running setup.py clean for fasttext
Failed to build fasttext
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fasttext, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: The error messages suggest that some include file, or project settings are incorrect or missing. You should go back to the fasttext website to check if you have satisfied all prerequisites for the installation. I just took a look on the fasttext website and it mentions that it builds on MacOS and Linux, but there is no mention of Windows. Seems rather odd for an open-source product.

Comment: Which web pages did you read after searching with a www search engine for `fastText installation Windows`? Did you read [Unable to install fastText for Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51683015/) or [fasttext-win](https://pypi.org/project/fasttext-win/) or [Building fastText Python wrapper from source under Windows](https://medium.com/@oleg.tarasov/building-fasttext-python-wrapper-from-source-under-windows-68e693a68cbb) or …?

Comment: I like on the last referenced page the last paragraph: *There should be no errors. Congratulations! You’ve just downloaded around 6 gigs of Windows SDK and build tools in order to install a 12 Kb Python wrapper!* :)

Comment: Many open-source Python projects in data-science/natural-language don't support Windows quite as well as Linux. Facebook doesn't seem to use Windows much, hence their FastText open-source release hasn't included the extra complexity/effort of ensuring things work on Windows. If you have free choice of systems, a lot of installations/troubleshooting will be at leat a little easier on Linux, in this particular domain.